# Converting DateTime field to another time zone?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, time, datetime

I'm using QGIS 2.16.3 and attempting to convert a number of datetime fields that are appearing in the incorrect default GMT +0 timezone. I would like to add, for example, 10 hours to accurately reflect the time zone of data collection.

So far I've attempted using the field calculator:

```
"Date_Field" +   ('10:00:00')
```

which just adds a string to the end (i.e. '2017-4-06 14:00:001')

I've also tried:

```
( "Date_Field") + to_time('10:00:00')
( "Date_Field") + to_datetime('10:00:00')  
to_datetime( "Date_Field") + to_datetime('10:00:00')
```

which gives me an error "Cannot convert '2017-04-06 14:00:00' to double", although I am able to convert the datetime field alone.

This seems like a simple, common operation for anyone working with different time zones. My only workaround is to create a CSV and edit the fields in a spreadsheet.

Comment: How are you storing this information? Is your underlying DB compatible with timestamps or is the information simply kept as a string?

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111209/date-format-conversion) can also help.

Comment: How about `to_datetime("Date_Field")  + to_interval('10 hours')` ?

Comment: I'm using a shapefile exported from a proprietary database but compatible with timestamps.

When I created a new string field with  to_datetime(  "Date_Field" ) I am able to use Time Manager on that field but not do any calculation.

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito , to_interval successfully added 10 hours!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Expression `to_datetime("Date_Field") + to_interval('10 hours')` will add 10 hours to the "Date_Field".

I have not tested fully, but it seems `to_interval()` accepts `month(s)` `day(s)` `hour(s)` and their combinations such as `'1 day 2 hours'`.

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito , this worked perfectly.
It also accepted the combination  '10 hours 01 minutes'

Comment: @nickislander I am glad it worked. Thanks for the `minutes` tip, too.

Comment: Bravo @Kazuhito!  A follow-up thought:  If daylight savings time shifted during the period that the original data was collected (say the offset changed from -8 to -7), then the user would need to apply the expression twice - once for just those records in the -8 period, then a second calculation for the -7 period records.  I have not tested, but this seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks @StuSmith. I agree with you. Perhaps keeping all of `"UTC"`, `"UTC-8h"`, `"UTC-7h"` fields in the attribute table will be helpful (and self-explanatory). Both time zones and DST time-shift are quite error-prone.